# LLCs and double-tax treaty in Portugal

Tags: taxes, limited-liability-company, portugal

I have a company in Belarus — a country that has no double-tax treaty with Portugal. My client, a representative of a Portuguese company, says that in order to wire money for my company's services, they'd have to pay taxes on the money going out to my company, since Portugal does not have a double-tax treaty with Belarus.

So, do Portuguese companies have to pay taxes on the payments they make to companies from countries where there's no double-tax treaty with Portugal?

**UPD:**

The taxes are not deducted from my fee, they are added on top of it (because the contract states how much my company should get, not how much they pay).

The reason I am asking this question is:

- It's just something that I was very surprised to hear. I know that in some countries (mine included) when sending money to a company registered in an off-shore jurisdiction (BVI, Caymans, etc) from your corporate account you have to pay a tax for simply sending the funds. But Belarus is anything but a tax heaven
- This could be used against me as an argument to negotiate the price in the future or, if I want to continue working with them, I'd have to incorporate somewhere else.

Comment: Even if this is true (which I doubt) - why would it be any problem of yours?

Comment: OT: Are you selling the famous parts for the Kamov helicopters?

Comment: @EarlGrey no, but if the price is good I think we can arrange something, comrade

Comment: @SJuan76 I have updated the question with more details

Comment: Belarus **is** a tax haven, if you are in the right sector
https://taxmoneyhavens.com/2018/01/17/belarus-a-tax-haven-for-the-digital-economy/
or as seen by the neighbors https://eng.belta.by/economics/view/polish-weekly-wprost-compares-belarus-to-tax-haven-98782-2017

Comment: @EarlGrey I am a resident of this so-called tax-heaven HTP myself. The info the article you have linked provides is outdated (since then the taxes have been increased for the payroll). I pay 1% of revenues and 9% dividend tax to take the money out. Comparing to the US/Scandinavia, one may call it tax heaven. But it's like saying a man without an arm is healthy compared to someone without both arms.

Comment: @AlexanderMikhalchenko if you like biomechanical analogies, tax haven must be seen as "If you need two arms to perform a job, you may prefer to employ two slaves with one arm each, rather than one decently paid employee with two arms."
Plus,  1% of revenues is not a tax haven? European OECD countries currently levy a corporate income tax rate of 21.7 percent, on average!

Comment: we're getting a little bit off-topic here, but IMO the only fair tax rate there is is a one percent less than 1%